# Open a file in binary mode and verify that the file ends with a specified string

Tags: perl

I have to write a script with the following specifications:

1. Open the file in binary mode.
2. Check that `000001 , 000002 - 0000031` comes in the same order in the
   file. There may be some more strings between any two `000001  000002`
   (which need to be verified)
3. File end with `000000`

I have tried this one, but it does not seem correct.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$SctFile = $ARGV[0] ;
$SccFile = $ARGV[1];
open FILE, $SctFile or die $!;
binmode FILE;
$sctfile =~ m/000001.*000002.*000000$/
```

Comment: For the values, are you indicating ASCII string (as in characters should be occurring) or binary values of various bytes (for example, with 000001 there are three bytes and byte 1 is 0, byte 2 is 0 and byte 3 is 1)?

Comment: Requirement is to search for  000001  string. Please help to write the regex for the same.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl

$SctFile = $ARGV[0] ;
$SccFile = $ARGV[1];


open FILE, $SctFile or die $!;
binmode FILE;
$sctfile =~ m/000001.*000002.*000000$/
I havr tried this one, but dont seems it is correct.

Comment: "Don't seems it is correct" is not a built-in error message in Perl.  As brian mentions below, you're not actually doing anything with the data in your files, so what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Has nobody seen that the OP had an typo in his program!? :)
When opening he uses $SctFile, but when matching he uses $sctfile...

Answer (score 3):

I think you're just missing the part where you get the file data. There are many ways to do this. You could slurp the file, which is the easiest (but not wisest) thing to do. You then match against the data you read from the file, not the filename. In Perl, once you open a filehandle, you have it available to get data from the file and you still need to get the data on your own:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 $SctFile = $ARGV[0] ;                               # get filename
 open FILE, $SctFile or die $!;                      # open file for reading
 binmode FILE;                                       # bin mode it for binary reading
 my $data = do { local $/; <FILE> };                 # slurp all the data

 if( $data =~ m/000001.*000002.*000000$/ ) { ... }   # match against the data
```

You can also [memory map the file](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/44) if you aren't going to change it. You never actually read it into RAM, so the file can be as large as you like without too much worry:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 use File::Map qw(map_file);

 $SctFile = $ARGV[0] ;

 map_file( my $map, $SctFile );

 if( $map =~ m/000001.*000002.*000000$/ ) { ... };
```